# UIScrollview does not show all the Content?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have attached UIHierarchy in the image attached. I want to scroll whole view and so contents of tableview within outer scrollview, not with tableview's scroll. For that, I have disabled tableview scroll. From the picture, tableview in given fixed height. MainView is set to have Equal width and equal height to MainScrollView.

Now the problem is, scrollview does not show all the contents of tableview. Whole view scrolls but does not reach to the end of the contents. I can not look at the last item in the tableview. Can somebody help me how to fix it and make it scroll all the items correctly. ?

[image]

Comment: table has static height or dynamic

Comment: tableview has static height of 285, but then later, it recalculates its height based on the number of items in it. each item has height of 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

> scrollView  : top , leading , trailing , bottom to superView
>
> mainView : top , leading , trailing , bottom to srollView ,  Equal width to top most view

then comes inner elements all elements should be hooked from top to bottom sure with leading and trailing constraints also , but you have to give each element a height constraint ( if it has no intrinsic content size like label and button ) , regarding the table hook it's  height as outlet and do this inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
self.tableHeight.constant = numberOfElements * elementHeight
```